# data.items.length always gives 10 as output

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, google-books

When I get a list of books I always get 10 as my data.items.length. Is this a limitation from the api itself?

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+search,
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(data){
                   for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {

                    some stuff
                    }
            results.innerHTML += some text


            },
            type: 'GET'
    });
```

Comment: Probably...check the api docs. Response probably gives you paging info also

Answer (score 5):

Google Books API will always return 10 results at a time unless otherwise specified. Search for "Pagination" at https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch. You can get up to 40 results using the maxResults=40 query parameter, and bring up the next set of results by using startIndex=X.

first 10 results:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test
```

next 10 results:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test&startIndex=10
```

Comment: request the maximum number of results per request:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test&maxResults=40

Answer (score 2):

Try using maxResults parameter and put a big value.